# what is arm-linux-gcc and how to install this in ubuntu

Tags: qt, compilation, embedded, arm

In compiling qt I found that there is a qws target called arm-linux-gcc. I looked around a bit but unable to figure out how and where to find this. I tried installing and apt-cache gave me following output.

```
apt-cache search armel
asterisk-prompt-fr-armelle - French voice prompts for Asterisk by Armelle Desjardins
rootstock - shellscript to create armel rootfs tarballs using a VM
rootstock-gtk - graphical frontend to the rootstock rootfs builder tool
icedtea-6-jre-cacao - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Cacao
installation-guide-armel - Ubuntu installation guide for armel
jasper - Configure a preinstalled ext2/3 system image
cpp-4.3-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C preprocessor
cpp-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C preprocessor
g++-4.3-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C++ compiler
g++-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C++ compiler
gcc-4.3-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C compiler
gcc-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C compiler
gcc-4.4-base-armel-cross - The GNU Compiler Collection (base package) (for cross-   compiling)
libc-bin-armel-cross - Embedded GNU C Library: Binaries (for cross-compiling)
libc-dev-bin-armel-cross - Embedded GNU C Library: Development binaries (for cross- compiling)
libc6-armel-cross - Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries (for cross-compiling)
libc6-dev-armel-cross - Embedded GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross-compiling)
libgcc1-armel-cross - GCC support library (for cross-compiling)
libgcc1-dbg-armel-cross - GCC support library (debug symbols)
libgfortran3-armel-cross - Runtime library for GNU Fortran applications
libgfortran3-dbg-armel-cross - Runtime library for GNU Fortran applications (debug  symbols)
libgmp3-dev-armel-cross - Multiprecision arithmetic library developers tools (for cross-compiling)
libgmp3c2-armel-cross - Multiprecision arithmetic library (for cross-compiling)
libgmpxx4ldbl-armel-cross - Multiprecision arithmetic library (C++ bindings) (for cross-compiling)
libgomp1-armel-cross - GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library
libgomp1-dbg-armel-cross - GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library (debug symbols)
libmpfr-dev-armel-cross - multiple precision floating-point computation developers   tools (for cross-compiling)
libmpfr4-armel-cross - multiple precision floating-point computation (for cross-compiling)
libmudflap0-4.4-dev-armel-cross - GCC mudflap support libraries (development files)
libmudflap0-armel-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries
libmudflap0-dbg-armel-cross - GCC mudflap shared support libraries (debug symbols)
libobjc2-dbg-armel-cross - Runtime library for GNU Objective-C applications (debug symbols)
libstdc++6-4.3-dbg-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.3-dev-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.3-pic-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.4-dbg-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.4-dev-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.4-pic-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (for cross-compiling)
linux-libc-dev-armel-cross - Linux support headers for userspace development (for cross-compiling)
tzdata-armel-cross - time zone and daylight-saving time data (for cross-compiling)
zlib1g-armel-cross - compression library - runtime (for cross-compiling)
zlib1g-dev-armel-cross - compression library - development (for cross-compiling)
cpp-4.1-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C preprocessor
cpp-4.2-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C preprocessor
g++-4.1-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C++ compiler
g++-4.2-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C++ compiler
gcc-4.1-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C compiler
gcc-4.2-arm-linux-gnueabi - The GNU C compiler
libmpfr1ldbl-armel-cross - multiple precision floating-point computation (for cross- compiling)
libobjc2-armel-cross - Runtime library for GNU Objective-C applications
libstdc++6-4.1-dbg-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.1-dev-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.1-pic-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
libstdc++6-4.2-dbg-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (debugging files)
libstdc++6-4.2-dev-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
libstdc++6-4.2-pic-armel-cross - The GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (shared library subset kit)
```

I think this has my system's arm compilers. Could some one assists to figure out to install "arm-linux-gcc"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are missing the gcc compiler with arm target set. This has been prepackaged in the ubuntu archive for quite a while, so you shouldn't need to build this from source.

`sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` to install

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled over this, while trying to cross-compile. After installing the gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi, make did not recognized it at all.
So you may also need to give **make** another hint. Calling it like

```
make CROSS_COMPILE=gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi-
```

does the trick for me.