# Cross Compile OpenSSH for ARM

Tags: openssl, arm, cross-compiling, zlib, openssh

Does anybody know how I can cross compile OpenSSH for ARM?
This is what I have done:

First I've downloaded Zlib source code, untarred it, built it and installed it using the following command lines:

```
   # ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/cross/arm

   # make 

   # make install
```

But then when I try to compile OpenSSH for the ARM target board, it gives the error "zlib missing" during the `./configure` process:

```
  # sudo LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/cross/arm/lib CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc PATH=$PATH:/home/arishop/arm-tool-chain/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/bin/ ./configure --host=arm-linux --with-zlib=/usr/local/cross/arm/ --prefix=/usr/local/cross/arm/openssh
```

Comment: I think you want to cross compile zlib, as well

Answer (score 44):

To cross compile openSHH for ARM (in my case a mini2440) I did following:

Install arm cross compiler -
(eg. [what is arm-linux-gcc and how to install this in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118051/what-is-arm-linux-gcc-and-how-to-install-this-in-ubuntu))

Download:

- Zlib
- OpenSSL
- OpenSSH

Build Zlib:

```
cd zlib-1.2.7
CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
./configure --prefix=$HOME/zlibArm
make 
make install
```

Build OpenSSL:

```
export cross=arm-linux-gnueabi-
cd openssl-1.0.1c
./Configure dist --prefix=$HOME/opensslArm
make CC="${cross}gcc" AR="${cross}ar r" RANLIB="${cross}ranlib"
make install
```

Build OpenSSH:

```
./configure --host=arm-linux --with-libs --with-zlib=$HOME/zlibArm --with-ssl-dir=$HOME/opensslArm --disable-etc-default-login CC=gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi-ar
make
```

More info at http://code.google.com/p/openssh4mini2440/wiki/HowTo, download source and read "build.sh"

Comment: +1 Excellent instructions and worked like a charm. (I was targeting `arm-linux-androideabi` but the process was nearly identical.)

Comment: The OpenSSL build failed on my Ubuntu system, had to change the one line to `export cross=arm-linux-gnueabi-` (remove the "gcc-" prefix)

Comment: Using openssh 5.3p1, I had to include ranlib

`./configure --host=arm-davinc-linux-gnueabi --with-libs --with-zlib=/opt/linux-2-6-31-xtools/x-tools/arm-davinci-linux-gnueabi/ --with-ssl-dir=/opt/linux-2-6-31-xtools/x-tools/arm-davinci-linux-gnueabi/ --disable-etc-default-login CC=arm-davinci-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-davinc-linux-gnueabi-ar RANLIB=arm-davinc-linux-gnueabi-ranlib`

Comment: The first make of zlib doesn't even use the ARM compiler. Is that intended? If I try making zlib with the ARM compiler, it fails with crc32 not working.

Comment: For the OpenSSL build, one can also do `export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-` prior to the `Configure` call, or equivalently use the `--cross_compile_prefix=arm-linux-gnueabi-` option.  This ties the configuration and building steps together so as to avoid the explicit configuration of `CC` and other variables.

Comment: Before building zlib I had to `export TARGETMACH=arm-linux-gnueabi;
export BUILDMACH=i686-pc-linux-gnu;
export CROSS=arm-linux-gnueabi;
export CC=${CROSS}-gcc;
export LD=${CROSS}-ld;
export AS=${CROSS}-as;` and later I modified for openssh cross compilation the following `CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR=arm-linux-gnueabi-ar`

Comment: zlib should include `export CHOST=arm-linux-gnueabihf`  not `CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

Comment: Thanks, that gave me a hint as to how to get my `i586-pc-msdosdjgpp` OpenSSL cross-compile working. I had `<io.h> missing` errors before but including the right version of gcc did the job.

Comment: I ended up here while searching a solution to cross compil OpenSSL for arm. Very nice instructions! I only had to change "arm-linux-gnueabi-" to "arm-linux-gnueabihf-" since my target platform supports hardware float

Comment: With OpenSSL 3.1.0, `./Configure dist --prefix=...` doesn’t work for me since `dist` is not recognized as a valid target.

Answer (score 11):

The board used is Mini6410. The requirement of OpenSSH includes zlib and OpenSSL. I prepare

- zlib 1.2.8
- OpenSSL 1.0.1e
- OpenSSH 6.4p1

My toolchain is built by crosstool-NG 1.15.2.  The toolchain configuration below is modified from arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi.

```
Arch:         armv6
CPU:          arm1176jzf-s
FPU:          vfp
Linux kernel: 2.6.38.8
binutils:     2.19.1a
gcc:          4.6.3
glibc:        2.11
gmp:          4.3.2
mpfr:         3.0.1
ppl:          0.11.2
cloog:        0.15.11
mpc:          0.9
```

Next I define three environment variables, `HOST`, `ROOTFS` and `SYSROOT`. `HOST` is arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi. `ROOTFS` is the root filesystem obviously. `SYSROOT` is the directory as the root directory for headers and libraries in the toolchain.

You might add `CFLAGS` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` pointing to your root filesystem so that the cross compiler can find what you have installed. However, I prefer not to set these variables. The alternative is installing those libraries in both `SYSROOT` and `ROOTFS`.

### First, compile zlib

```
AR=$HOST-ar CC=$HOST-gcc RANLIB=$HOST-ranlib ./configure --prefix=$ROOTFS/usr
make
make install
```

### Second, compile OpenSSL

```
./Configure linux-armv4 shared zlib-dynamic --prefix=/usr
make CC=$HOST-gcc AR="$HOST-ar r" RANLIB=$HOST-ranlib
make CC=$HOST-gcc AR="$HOST-ar r" RANLIB=$HOST-ranlib INSTALL_PREFIX=$ROOTFS install
```

Note that `--prefix` is set to `/usr` instead of `$ROOTFS/usr`. The reason is that if you set `--prefix` to `$ROOTFS/usr`, it will try to access configuration files in `$ROOTFS/usr` in runtime on Mini6410, which does not exist. The installation path specified in Makefile is `$INSTALL_PREFIX/$PREFIX`, so we use `$ROOTFS` for `$INSTALL_PREFIX`.

### Finally, compile OpenSSH

1. `./confgure --host=$HOST --prefix=/usr`
2. Remove the variable `STRIP_OPT` and `check-config` in the rule `install` in Makefile.
3. `make && make DESTDIR=$ROOTFS install`
4. Boot your Mini6410 and use command `ssh-keygen` to generate host keys.

The reason using `/usr` for `--prefix` is the same as OpenSSL. If you specify `--prefix=$ROOTFS/usr`, you will not be able to execute command `scp`.

`STRIP_OPT` have to be removed because it is impossible to use `/usr/bin/install` on x86-64 to strip binaries on ARM. The rule `check-config` will run the generated `sshd` on the host, so we have to avoid that.

In the last step, check Makefile and find the rule `host-key`. And The next line is `@if [ -z "$(DESTDIR)" ] ; then`, which means it does nothing if the length of `$(DESTDIR)` is nonzero. Thus, we must generate these keys manually on Mini6410:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa1 -f /usr/etc/ssh_host_key -N ""
ssh-keygen -t dsa -f /usr/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key -N ""
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /usr/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key -N ""
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /usr/etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -N ""
```

Comment: Small add-on, add zlib location when configuring openSSL using options: `--with-zlib-include=$ROOTFS/usr/include --with-zlib-lib=$ROOTFS/usr/lib`

Comment: This has helped me tremendously. The part about removing `STRIP_OPT` and `check-config` could have been more clear. Also I needed to add `--with-zlib=$ROOTFS/usr` to the configure of OpenSSH.

Answer (score 1):

I do like this

```
CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc RANLIB=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib ./Configure linux-armv4 --prefix=$OPENSSLARM --openssldir=$OPENSSLARM

make CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc AR="arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar r" RANLIB="arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ranlib"

make install
```