# undefined reference to `main'

Tags: gcc, makefile

When i compiling  OpenSSL i have next error:

```
/home/sim/LINUX/DevKit8000/Linux/tools/Cross_compiler_Devkit8000/arm-2007q3/bin/../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib/crt1.o: In function `_start': init.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `main' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compiling on DEBIAN for ARMv7 linux.

```
export cross=arm-linux-gnueabi-
./Configure no-asm linux-armv4 -march=armv7-a --prefix=$HOME/opensslArm
make CC=«${cross}gcc» AR=«${cross}ar r» RANLIB=«${cross}ranlib»
```

I look example in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841919/cross-compile-openssh-for-arm?rq=1)

Comment: You linking library as executable. Compile it (`-c`) to object file(s) (`.o`), then use `ar` to pack it(s) to `.a`. BTW, do you banned on Google?

Comment: where should I put (-с)?  Make file created automatically from ./Configure.