# Eclipse CDT - Link libcrypto.so for cross compiling

Tags: c++, eclipse, openssl, cross-compiling, eclipse-cdt

I want to cross compile a C++ program, which is using some OpenSSL files:

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
```

Because the path of the cross compiler (`/opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include`) is different to the default `/usr/include` path, where all the OpenSSL header files are, I had to set the include path with right click on project -> properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols --> Add... -> `/usr/include` to include the header files.

Same with the libcrypto.so :

...C/C++ General --> Libraries --> Add... `crypto`

...C/C++ General --> Library Paths --> Add... `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` (in this folder I found the librypto.so)

When building my project I get following error:

```
/opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so when searching for -lcrypto
    /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a when searching for -lcrypto
    /opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.4.1/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
```

Seems to be a linking error, but I don´t know why. Thanks for help.

Comment: Which version of OpenSSL are you using? Where is this come from: `/opt/crosstool/arm-none-linux-gnueabi`? (Its OK, I'm trying to set-up a test rig to test an answer).

Comment: I´m using version 1.0.1. The path is the path to my cross compiler, it was the default path after installing my cross compiler. In this path I have all the folders needed for my embedded hardware, some extra libraries for the hardware and also default libraries (and header files), but not the OpenSSL libraries. I tried to copy the libcrypto.so files into the folders of the cross compiler, but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, finally solved the problem. I didn´t know that I had to configure OpenSSL for using it to cross compile with ARM.

Just start your terminal and type:

```
    export cross=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
    cd openssl-1.0.1s
    ./Configure dist --prefix=$HOME/opensslArm
    make CC="${cross}gcc" AR="${cross}ar r" RANLIB="${cross}ranlib"
    make install
```

Now you have a folder called opensslArm in your home directory. In this folder you will find all the header files and the library itself. So in Eclipse add the path to the opensslArm/include to your includes and opensslArm/lib to your Library paths. Look here for further information: [Cross Compile OpenSSH for ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841919/cross-compile-openssh-for-arm)