# fatal error including header for cross-compilation

Tags: c, ubuntu, cross-compiling, openwrt

I'm using ubuntu and I'm trying to cross-compile a C program for OpenWrt distribution.
I tried to compile the code on ubuntu using `gcc` and it's working correctly.
But when I tried to compile it using `mips-openwrt-linux-gcc` I get errors about headers (`fatal error: openssl/conf.h: No such file or directory`).

Main C file is main.c , I used to compile it using `gcc main.c -lssl -lcrypto -o exec` on ubuntu , now for cross-compilation I'm using `mips-openwrt-linux-gcc main.c -lssl -lcrypto -o exec` and this causes the problem I just mentioned.

Should I include headers in the toolchain directory? If yes how to do it for openwrt target?

Comment: Maybe the other compiler doesn't have "openssl/conf.h" in his search directory.

Comment: You have to "install" OpenSSL into your cross-compilation toolchain. For hints, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841919/cross-compile-openssh-for-arm

Comment: Why not use the build toolchain OpenWRT provides? That will download/compile/build all required tools, libs, etc your target needs. And read the build instructions for your device on their website.

Comment: @Olaf can you explain with details please ?

Comment: What was unclear? Surprisngly OpenWRT has a website and a Wiki with documentation. It might not be easy, but I can tell first-hand it works.

Comment: Another hint: https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=148259#p148259