# Cross compiling to arm with openssl library

Tags: openssl, arm, cross-compiling

I followed this stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841919/cross-compile-openssh-for-arm) to cross compile the openssl for arm. I was able to successfully do the steps, and I have an folder named as opensslArm in /home directory. However when I am trying to compile just a hello world program by using the following command

```
 arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld.c -o sslarm -static
```

It gets me this error.

```
/usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:56:33: fatal error: openssl/opensslconf.h: No such file or directory
```

Following is the program that I had been using to compile (Nothing fancy, I just added a include statement to check whether cross compilation works before using real function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h> 

int main(){
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

Could somebody please help me how to correctly compile to ARM with the linking of openssl libraries. I feel that I am not correctly linking the compiled openssl library.  I tried searching in the internet and could not find an answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try adding this to your `gcc` command: `--sysroot=<prefix_path>`

Comment: I tried with command `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  helloworld.c -o sslarm -static --sysroot=/home/heshan` but still getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure the error is exactly the same? At a minimum the paths in the error should be different. It should not have `/usr/include`. The exact error matters so please double check.

Comment: `helloworld.c:2:26: fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory` Exact error

Comment: How is that the same error? Please be more precise going forward so as not to waste time. Anyway, looks like you gave the wrong `sysroot` value or you haven't installed the `openssl` headers. Is there actually a `/home/heshan/openssl/rsa.h` file? If not, where did you install the openssl cross compiled build?

Comment: sorry, I am just a beginner :(  `/home/heshan/opensslArm/include/openssl` does contains the `rsa.h` file. I tried running `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc helloworld.c -o sslarm -static --sysroot=/home/heshan/opensslArm/include/openssl` but gets the same `helloworld.c:2:26: fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory` error as before.

Comment: What `--prefix` value did you use when you built openssl and did you do `make install` when you built `openssl`?

Comment: I used `--prefix=$HOME/opensslArm`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206641/discussion-between-kaylum-and-heshan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer credits : @kaylum

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/heshan/opensslArm -I/home/heshan/opensslArm/include helloworld.c -o sslarm -static
```