# make[1]: arm-linux-gcc: Command not found in ubuntu

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, kernel, ubuntu-11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is arm-linux-gcc and how to install this in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118051/what-is-arm-linux-gcc-and-how-to-install-this-in-ubuntu)

While I'm trying this command

```
$ make ARCH=arm devkit8000 defconfig
```

I get this error:

```
make[1]: arm-linux-gcc: Command not found
make[1]: arm-linux-gcc: Command not found
scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/arm/Kconfig
***
*** You have not yet configured your kernel!
*** (missing kernel .config file)
***
*** Please run some configurator (e.g. "make oldconfig" or
*** "make menuconfig" or "make xconfig").
***
make[3]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `devkit8000'.  Stop.
make: *** [devkit8000] Error 2
```

How can i solve this error?

Answer (score 6):

Do you have ARM toolchain installed? If there is no such package in Ubuntu you can download it from the internet and add it to your $PATH.

Take a look at [what is arm-linux-gcc and how to install this in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118051/what-is-arm-linux-gcc-and-how-to-install-this-in-ubuntu)

EDIT:
It might be, that your makefile is looking for different filenames, than you have.

Try locating `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` file. Go to that directory and you may create links for each file with `arm-linux-gnueabi-` prefix.

Try after `sudo su`:

```
ln -s arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc arm-linux-gcc
ln -s arm-linux-gnueabi-cc arm-linux-cc
```

etc.

Might help, but I do not guarantee. Usually works ;-)

Comment: thanks for ur reply ,
the error still happen although installing this
$sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
???

Comment: @MohamedNada try with my edit

Comment: `make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi` instead of `make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-`